# Using centimeters exact measurement in pixels iReport image

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Well, i have a image in *iReport* that must be exact **10x8 cm**. Making a conversion to pixels i got: `377.952756 (10cm) x 302.362205 (8cm)`. But *iReport* just accept integer values, not double values as i expected.

How can i do a exact **10x8cm** in *iReport* ?

Comment: Does a rounding error of 0.3% (less than 1/3 of a millimeter) really matter?

Comment: yeah, really matter. I nned a exact measurement because of my customer really wants this.

Comment: @MrLanhellas: Are they going to measure the result with a vernier caliper...?

Comment: Yeah, something like this Matti Virkkunen, the important is that i really need this correct value. I need know if it's possible or not.

Comment: @MrLanhellas: After some recalculation, I have figured out that if you use the size 378x302, the error will be about 0.1mm on both axis. That isn't even visible to the human eye at a normal reading distance. You're worrying too much. Your customer quite literally won't be able to see the difference.

Comment: So, thanks for your attetion. I'll use this and try to be aproved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `Tools->Options` , in the General tab there is a option "Unit" , here you can choose cm. Be aware that the page/band itself will always be measured in pixels (but this can do the trick for your image).

Please refer to this link for a common asked question: [Units](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/522034/default-unit-mmcmetc)

Comment: I already tried it but the image object continue being measuring in pixels.